# How can I get V100 GPU in Colab?

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory

I have bought the Colab Pro, whereas I can only apply for the P100 for most of the time. V100 can run almost 2 times faster than P100. How can I get a V100 manually?

Answer (score 4):

I have also been using Colab Pro for a long time, and as far as I know these resources are allocated according to Google's availablity. I have been using `Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB` most of the time, but at random times I get assigned a `Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB`.

BTW, to print your device name, you can use this command in Pytorch:

```py
import torch
 
torch.cuda.get_device_name(device=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's about three months since I started using Colab pro, and ever since, I haven't even a single time gotten the V100, and most of the time, I got the P100 and some times T4.

And to get the GPU that you are using in Colab, the best way is to use the command below:

```
!nvidia-smi
```